# Is there an actual two-weapons block animation?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I know of the mod adding the block animation when dual-wielding, but the block is actually done with a single weapon. 
I've tried seraching on the Nexus but had no luck.

To rephrase: Is there an actual animation using 2 single-handed weapons to block? 
I imagine the weapons being "crossed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition...

The idle stance animation you see when dual-wielding (the one where you raise one hand in the air) is actually named the blocking stance for dual-wield in the game assets, but the blocking stance mechanic itself is never implemented in the finished product. I found out about it when making PCEA 1.0

So if you're asking "does the game actually has dual-wield block asset?" the answer is yes, it does, only repurposed

If you're asking "does the game has a dual-wield block asset that has never actually been used?" the answer is no, it doesn't

P.S: if you're wondering what the original dual-wield idle animation looks like, I don't know. I don't see anything named that in the game asset. If you're wondering where I found out about it, it's somewhere in the animation group data accessible through Creation Kit (I haven't touched it for about a year no and I don't have Skyrim installed)

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I'm aware of the fact that the original game doesn't have it, was wondering about mods.

For clarity, he question could be rephrased to "is there a blocking animation actually executed with 2 weapons?"

Comment: The answer of that would be no, there isn't

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try this? http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9247/?
Though it says it will be a little laggy, I think it is worth a try

Comment: I think this is the actual mod the OP is referring to.  Sounds like he wants a different type of animation than that one.  But it's the mod that I use and enjoy, and it does allow you to block while dual wielding, so have an upvote!

Comment: Yes, as Caleb stated that is the mod i'm using - and it works great! - but i was wondering if there is another animation available, as that one kinda breaks immersion to me ( why would you block with just one weapon when you have two?)

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any other mod available, but you can always create your own!

Answer (score 0):

If there is, it's unusable since the button you would use to block is used to attack with your offhand weapon.  That's the major drawback with using two weapons.  You can do much more damage much more quickly, but it leaves you vulnerable as well.

Unless, you're asking if the animation exists regardless of usability?  If that's the case, then you'll have to do some digging around around in the animation folder to find that.  I don't have the tools available at the moment to help, I'm afraid.

Comment: There is a configurable mod that allows you to use another button to block, the one in Kim's answer.

Comment: Indeed there is.  I thought you were asking if the animation existed in the game period (or at least a different one from what that mod uses), though, not if there was a way to block with two weapons.